# Intellisense Doesn't Display Custom Class Members

Tags: c#, asp.net, intellisense

I'm writing a deserializer like this:

```
public class MyObjectConverter : JavaScriptConverter
{
 public override object Deserialize(IDictionary<string, object> dictionary, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
 {    
    MyObjectClass obj = new MyObjectClass();
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey("name"))
    {
      obj.
    }
```

I have a using statement that links the MyObjectClass with the proper namespace but for some reason that I don't understand, I'm not getting the properties of the object in the intellisense. 
Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save your work and try restarting Visual Studio

Comment: Are you sure that the data members in MyObjectClass are public?